# French residence permit for non-EEA spouse of EEA national

Tags: resident-permit, france

I am Italian and my wife is Mauritian.

We moved to France from the UK. I am trying to understand if she needs a residence permit or not.

I found a page on the French government website stating that since she is the spouse of a European national she doesn't need any permit.

But when we tried to register for the social security (CPAM) they said that she does need one.
Also, when we crossed the border the officers didn't stamp our passports so we don't have a proof of entry, which may affect the cost of the application.

Note that my wife has a UK permanent residence card.

Comment: What "page on the French government website" are you referring to?  It's difficult to reconcile the conflicting information if we don't know precisely what information we're being asked to reconcile.

Answer (score 3):

Your wife needs a residence *card,* which is distinct from a residence *permit,* in order to reside in France for more than three months.

Here's some more information, from [Séjour en France de la famille d'un citoyen européen](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2653), choosing the option for "other nationality [than European or Swiss]":

> Les membres majeurs de votre famille (ou de plus de 16 ans s'ils souhaitent travailler) **doivent obligatoirement détenir un titre de séjour.**
>
> Ils doivent le demander dans les 3 mois de leur entrée en France.
>
> Dans un délai maximum de 6 mois, une carte de séjour *membre de la famille d'un citoyen de l'Union* leur est délivrée, sous réserve d'absence de menace pour l'ordre public.
>
> Cette carte a la même durée de validité que votre titre de séjour, ou si vous ne l'avez pas demandé, que la durée de séjour à laquelle vous pouvez prétendre, dans la limite de 5 ans.
>
> Le droit au séjour de votre famille prend fin avec le vôtre. Cependant, dans certaines situations et sous certaines conditions, votre famille peut continuer à vivre sans vous en France (en cas de divorce ou de décès ou si vous quittez la France, etc.).
>
> Si la carte doit être renouvelée, il faut faire la demande dans les 2 mois qui précèdent son expiration.

(emphasis in original)

Translation:

> Adult members of your family (or older than 16 years if they want to work) **must obtain a residence title.**
>
> They must apply for it within three months of their entry into France.
>
> With six months, a residence card *of a member of the family of a citizen of the Union* is issued, subject to the absence of a threat to public safety.
>
> This card has the same period of validity as your residence title, or, if you haven't applied for one, as the expected duration of your residence, up to 5 years.
>
> Your family's right of residence ends with yours.  Nevertheless, in certain situations and under certain conditions, your family may continue to live in France without you (in case of divorce or death, or if you leave France, etc.).
>
> If the card must be renewed, it is necessary to make the application within the two months preceding its expiration.